# "Invalid class" error when creating new object for Win32_OperatingSystem class

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm currently working on some code that needs to get some properties from the [Win32_OperatingSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239(v=vs.85).aspx) class and have some code that looks like the following:

```
var managmentObject = new System.Management.ManagementObject("Win32_OperatingSystem.Name='TotalVirtualMemorySize'");
var memory = (ulong) managmentObject["TotalVirtualMemorySize"]*1024ul;
```

This code is more or less the same as the sample provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1509708/1185), but I have been getting a System.Managment.ManagmentException with the message "Invalid class" when I run it. Any ideas what might be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `"Win32_OperatingSystem=@"` to get the current instance of the [Win32_OperatingSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class. `@` means that an object is singleton, which is mentioned towards the bottom of the MSDN documentation in the "Remarks" section.

For info about paths in WMI please read [Describing an Instance Object Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389977(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: So does that mean you can't directly access the `TotalVirtualMemorySize` property of the class?

Comment: What do you mean? Accessing a static property like in C#?

Comment: If you mean static properties then there are no static properties in WMI. You should get an object instance first to get its property values.

Answer (score 0):

As Yoh Deadfall said and also mentioned [here](http://Win32_OperatingSystem%20is%20a%20singleton%20class.%20To%20get%20the%20single%20instance,%20use%20%22@%22%20for%20the%20key.),`Win32_OperatingSystem` is a `singleton class`. To get the single instance, use "@" for the key.

```
var managmentObject = new ManagementObject("Win32_OperatingSystem=@");
var memory = (ulong)managmentObject["TotalVirtualMemorySize"] * 1024ul;
```